# Searching a string for a time. Java

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to get a If statement to work in java.

I have a *`String startTime;`*

I want to make it so 06:00 to 9:59 is a peak time and some other times but I just want to get one if statement working right first

i use

```
*if (startTime >= "06:00" && startTime <= "9:59");*
```

I know that strings dont really search like that but I was told by the instructor that we can use strings to accomplish the task really easy.  I was also told to only use the main method not use other classes

it comes up with:

```
**the operator >= is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String, java.lang.String**
```

Comment: The compilation error should be clear in this case, you can't use comparison operators with non-primitive data types (in this case, String). I don't readily see a way that this can be done easily with Strings, unless they're passed to the constructor of some other object which parses time and dates.

Comment: best solution will be if you convert your strings to dates, and then compare them

Comment: `String` can not be compared using relational operators (ie `>=`, `<=`, etc)

Answer (score 1):

Use `String.compareTo` to accomplish this.

```
if (startTime.compareTo("06:00")>0 && startTime.compareTo("09:59")<0) ...;
```

Comment: Thanks well its not coming up with an errors now,  yeah, thanks for the suggesting.

Comment: that wouldn't work all the time, forexample "09:59".compareTo("9:59") will return a number less than 0; so the if statement goes wrong. you should first transform the string to Date or integer

Comment: @nafas Thanks for pointing that out, it should be 09:59 (assuming the string is also in the same format) - a little bug I copied from the question. Fixed that.

Answer (score 0):

Break your string in to the hours and minutes (use String.split), then convert the two to integers (use Integer.parseInt), then comparisons are easy.

Answer (score -1):

String is an object and it does not have operators like `<=` and `>=`.

You can compare two strings using `equals()` and `equalsIgnoreCase()` methods or else you can check references of string using `==`.

In your case since you are comparing two strings, you will not be able to determine if one string is greater than other unless you convert it to Java Date object or to Double object or else you can also use `compareTo()` method.

Comment: Why -1, please let me know whether anything is wrong in my answer, that way I can also learn.

Comment: I was going to use a double but then could not get my head around using a colon so I gave up on that.  I was then going to use the Gregorian date object, but the lecturer said that we can use a string is the easiest method for us right now.  so I went ok I will try that but couldn't figure out how to search,  now it seems so simple.

Comment: Yeah, but then I think it should not lead to -1. I had given different options by which you can compare objects that contains digits. Your choice though. Thanks.

Comment: The lecturer said that we can assume that he will only test with proper hours nothing else in the startTime field he wont put in anything but numbers.  Once it is done I will be learning the gregorian date part of it.